# Android Customized Actionbar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, themes

I'm trying to customize an actionbar at an android application.

I followed the [google tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

But it didn't work.

This is the code of my themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<color name="custom_white_color">#ffffff</color>
<color name="custom_blue_color">#2E4372</color>

<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/custom_white_color</item>
</style>
```

At the "AndroidManifest" I'm calling this theme for the application

```
android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
```

But when I execute this code the following error occurs

```
03-03 00:44:43.456    2467-2467/br.com.lzl.colorlist E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: br.com.lzl.colorlist, PID: 2467
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.lzl.colorlist/br.com.lzl.colorlist.HomeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:151)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
        at br.com.lzl.colorlist.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
```

If I try to use Theme.Appcompat the customization doesn't work.

Does anybody got a clue to solve this?

Thank you since now!

Comment: did you import the appcompat library?

Comment: I suppose I should try find out whether you were looking to do a Material, Holo, or some other theme?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Android Studio and it already add AppCompat to the library.

Comment: I'm trying to customize karaokyo the actionBar, and making the background white.

Comment: I know what you are trying to do. The tutorial you are following is obsolete with the new material design guideline. Please do a little research and answer my original question.

Comment: Now I understood, sorry for misunderstanding. I want to use Holo theme.

Comment: For Holo, switch your `ActionBarActivity` to `Activity` and you can follow that tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Holo theme:**

Switch your `ActionBarActivity` to `Activity` and you will be able to follow that tutorial.

**For Material theme:**

Change your parent theme to `Theme.AppCompat.Light` (or something similar) and customize your action bar background via the `colorPrimary` property and the action bar text color via the `android:textColorPrimary` property:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FFF</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#2E4372</item>
</style>
```

[image]

See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: If I use "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" the color of the actionBar gets themed, and I want to use the customized color.

Either way I can't make the actionBar be as I want it to be

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem. I made this code.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#2E4372'; font-weight: bold;> ColorList </font>"));
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_test_menu_2));
```

And I used a simple theme

```
<style name="ThemeCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

So I got a white actionBar, but the menu button is still black for the theme.

That's not a problem.

Thank you guys